# How to determine item ContentType in FormControl (FieldIterator for instance)?

Tags: content-type, custom-form, spcontext

I've implemented my ListFieldIterator to change the way field controls rendered.
I'd like to change the behaviour of form depending on the item content type, 
but any attempts to determine ContentTypeId from the code returns wrong result.

```
ListFieldIterator.ListItem.ContentTypeId

SPContext.Current.ListItem.ContentTypeId
```

are always return

> 0x00C2208B8CE6E1422CADC1C521EAB2A68B

(which is invalid content type id)

There's a property LoadContentTypes in SPContext class, but setting it TRUE for `SPContext.Current` or `FieldIterator.ItemContext` makes no difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the method with determining [ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.contenttype.aspx) in custom [ListFieldIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listfielditerator.aspx) from query string, *ItemContext* contains property *ContentType*. But this property is internal and therefore could not be used directly in custom [ListFieldIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listfielditerator.aspx) implementation.

Below is presented wrapper for retriving [ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.contenttype.aspx) based on corresponding property for [SPContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontext.aspx)  (Reflection is used here)

```
        private SPContentType CurrentContentType
        {
            get {
                var ct = typeof(SPContext).GetProperty("ContentType", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(ItemContext, null) as SPContentType;
                return ct;
            }
        }
```

Using *CurrentContentType* property, content type could be determined in custom [ListFieldIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listfielditerator.aspx) implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution actually the best one, because it allows to determine content type even if it isn't specified in query string.

Comment: I agree and glad that was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to determine content type in this case is to analize HTTP query string:

```
new SPContentTypeId(this.Context.Request.QueryString["ContentTypeId"])
```